# "List<Object>" and "String" cast declaration issue

Tags: java

-Experts.

I'm instancing a general method(A) that returns a List type file. In my case, I know for sure that the file I'm going to obtain is a string and I would like to specify so in the method call. But, obviously, the programs show a type missmatch error. Just specifying `List<Object>` wouldn't be a solution because I need this file to be a string argument input for another method(B).

The method(A) has the following definition:

```
public <T> List<T> find(String queryString, Object param){}
```

I instance the above-mentioned method(A) this way:

```
String idioma;
idioma = miDao.find("SELECT c.idioma FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param",o1);
```

The result is that idioma cannot be resolved as a variable. But my goal is to get the String idioma to use it as an input of a entity property:

```
public void setIdioma(String idioma) {
    this.idioma = idioma;
}
```

Does anyone know how could I solve this missmatch file problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the method find(..) ? your question isn't really clear

Comment: You are trying to assign List returned from method to String variable. What do you expect to happen? BTW. you mentioned something about 'file' where there is nothing about `File` in your code example.

Comment: Change `miDao.find(...)` to `miDao.<String>find(...).get(0)`?

Comment: The file you're going to obtain is a string?

Comment: The method(A) `public <T> List<T> find(String queryString, Object param){}` is going to return one String that is the one I would like to pass to another method(B) as a String argument input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` gives you a list of `string` so you have to work with a list as output_

```
List<String> idiomas;
idiomas = (List<String>)miDao.find("SELECT c.idioma FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param",o1);
if (idiomas.size()>0){
  idioama = idiomas.get(0)
}
```

Comment: Finally,
a) I declared a `List<Object> idiomas`
b) invocated the find method `idiomas = miDao.find("SELECT c.idioma FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param",o1);`
c) assigned the idiomas value to the String idioma variable `idioma = (String) idiomas.get(0);`
Thank you very much for your great answer!

Answer (score -1):

Finally this worked:

1. I declared a `List<Object> idiomas`
2. Invocated the find method:

   idiomas = miDao.find("SELECT c.idioma FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param",o1);
3. Assigned the idiomas value to the String idioma variable:

   idioma = (String) idiomas.get(0);